# Question about $R^{2}$ and $R^{3}$

Tags: geometry, polygons

I know that $R^{2}$ is a subset of $R^{3}$. If I have a 2-D cirle $A$ and also a 
 2-D rectangular polygon  B that are both contained in $R^{3}$, would $ A \oplus B$ be 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional shape?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$. We can identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the subset $\{(x,y,0)~|~x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it is not truly a subset. This is a subtle but important distinction for questions like yours.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, would planes in a 3-D space be considered 2-D? Would planes be considered 2-D and also a subset of $R^{3}$. Would the sum of two planes be 3-D or 2-D?

Comment: The notion of dimension is complicated, but if we are talking about (hyper)-planes, then things are pretty simple. A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a two-dimensional subspace in the sense that it has a basis consisting of two vectors. (I'm not sure how much linear algebra you know, but that's what I'm using here.) The direct sum of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$ and is four-dimensional as a subspace, since it has a basis consisting of four vectors.

Comment: When I say "the direct sum of two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$" I am being a little fast and loose... technically points in the direct sum are of the form $((x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3))$, which we identify with the point $(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3)\in \mathbb{R}^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the direct sum, I suppose that  you think at $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. In this case,$\mathbb{R}^2$  is **not** a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

It is true that $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains infinitely many subsets( the ''planes'' in the ''space'') that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (as a vector space), but the elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, also if they are in a plane, are represented by three coordinates $(x,y,z)$.

For the last question: it is not clear what you means by the direct sum of a circle and a polygon but, intuitively, if the two figure stay in a same plane, the subspace that contains the two is this same plane, if they are in different planes then the subspace that contains the two is the whole $3$-D space.

Comment: I'm talking about the Minkowski sum